# Internal Server Error while using jtable in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, internal-server-error, jquery-jtable

I am using laravel 4. As per instructions of jtable I have included scripts and code but while using it when page is loading an ajax request is fired and it returns error code of 500.

Route Code:

```
Route::any('/staff',array('as'=>'staff','uses' => 'HomeController@getPersons'))->before('auth');
```

View Code:

```
$('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Table of people',
                actions: { 
                    listAction: document.url 
                }, 
                fields: { 
                    PersonId: { 
                        key: true, 
                        create: false, 
                        edit: false, 
                        list: false 
                    }, 
                    Name: { 
                        title: 'Author Name', 
                        width: '40%' 
                    }, 
                    Age: { 
                        title: 'Age', 
                        width: '20%' 
                    }, 
                    RecordDate: { 
                        title: 'Record date', 
                        width: '30%', 
                        type: 'date', 
                        create: false, 
                        edit: false 
                    } 
                } 
            }); 
            $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load'); 

//If i use {{URL::route('staff',array('action'=>'list')) }} then Ajax is not fired so please also provide solution regading this

Controller Code: 
public function getPersons() 
    { 
             if(Request::ajax()) 
             { 
                $row=DB::table('people')->get(); 
                $recordCount=DB::table('people')->count(); 
                $jTableResult = array(); 
                $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK"; 
                $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordCount; 
                $jTableResult['Records'] =$row; 
                Response::json($jTableResult); 
             } 
            return View::make('backend.staff'); 
    }
```

View that is generated:

Table of people
Author Name
Age 
Record date 
No data available!
+ Add new record

Answer (score 0):

something worth trying, add a loop and add to the array from the loop. I had to do that for something very similar to this.

EDIT

could also look at [this:](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json)

I wrote a [tutorial](http://emansprogramminghub.blogspot.com/2014/03/using-jtable-with-laravel-4.html) on this as well.